# Multiple variables not aligned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having issues aligning multiple variables in a table. I want to match the year in each column and show data if present, if not show '0'. Ive attached an image of whats happening, column d's data should be in 2011.[image]

Table

```
<% @a.zip(@b, @c, @d) do |a, b, c, d| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= a.year %></td>

        <td><% if a.nil? %>0<% else %><%= a.id %><% end %></td>
        <td><% if a.nil? %>0<% else %><%= "%.2f" % (a.avg/227) %><% end %></td>

        <td><% if b.nil? %>0<% else %><%= b.id %><% end %></td>
        <td><% if b.nil? %>0<% else %><%= "%.2f" % (b.avg/227) %><% end %></td>

        <td><% if c.nil? %>0<% else %><%= c.year %> <%= c.id %><% end %></td>
        <td><% if c.nil? %>0<% else %><%= "%.2f" % (c.avg/227) %><% end %></td>

        <td><% if d.nil? %>0<% else %><%= d.id %><% end %></td>
        <td><% if d.nil? %>0<% else %><%= "%.2f" % (d.avg/227) %><% end %></td>

    </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Controller

```
  @a = Result.where(id: params[:id_select]).group('year').where('data > 0').select('AVG(data) AS data, year as year, COUNT(id) AS id').order('year ASC')

  @b = Result.where(id: params[:id_select]).group('results.year').where('data > 0').select('AVG(data) AS data, year as year, COUNT(id) AS id').where('id = ?', '0').order('year ASC')

  @c = Result.where(id: params[:id_select]).group('results.year').where('data > 0').select('AVG(data) AS data, year as year, COUNT(id) AS id').where('id = ?', '1').order('year ASC')

  @d = Result.where(id: params[:id_select]).group('results.year').where('data > 0').select('AVG(data) AS data, year as year, COUNT(id) AS id').where('id = ?', '2').order('year ASC')
```

Comment: mind putting what you are geting

Comment: The image is a screen shot of what i'm getting via the code. Column D's data should be in 2011 (2.04 avg and Id of 1), but it shows up first in 2007.

Comment: Why do you have two `where` clauses both setting expectations against `id`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `@d` array likely only has one element (the 2011 data).

When you `zip` it with the other larger arrays, that data is associated with the other 2007 results.

eg:

```
2.1.5 :001 > a = [1,2,3]
 => [1, 2, 3]
2.1.5 :002 > b = [4,5,6]
 => [4, 5, 6]
2.1.5 :003 > c = [7]
 => [7]
2.1.5 :004 > a.zip(b,c)
 => [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, nil], [3, 6, nil]]
```

You need to be querying the DB by year, rather than just asking for whatever data is available by id.